# JMonkeyEngine in Eclipse

Tags: java, 3d, eclipse

I wanted to try the JMonkey engine, so I downloaded the JMonkey sdk, but I don't want to work in the JME IDE, I would rather like to work with Eclipse, since I already started a game project there, and I only want to replace the game engine(the code is modular, so i can do that) form pure LWJGL to JME. I found this tutorial:
http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:setting_up_jme3_in_eclipse
But that won't work, when I add the jar-s then there is no com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication anywhere there, as the tutorial suggests. Also where are the correct native files? I googled, but I can't find any example projects of Eclipse, or any decent explanations how to set up JME in Eclipse properly.

Comment: I thought the SDK was pretty much wired to the IDE. You could probably use the jar files, but I'm pretty sure you can't use all those build in tools like JME provides.

Comment: The link that I posted says:
"For development with the jMonkeyEngine 3, we recommend to use the jMonkeyEngine SDK. 
 Alternatively, you can use your favorite IDE: In this tutorial we show how to download and set up the latest nightly build of the jMonkeyEngine 3 for use with the Eclipse IDE. Instructions for NetBeans IDE are also available."

Comment: What I meant was:  Are you able to use the graphical tools you have in JME  in Eclipse as well?

Comment: I don't think so, but I saw there was some kind of plugin, but I didn't investigate that.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, I downloaded an older version of JME by accident. I now downloaded the proper version, and I did exactly as the tutorial said, and it worked. Sorry for bothering.